# Table borders between columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

Say I have a simple table like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        cell
    </td>
    <td>
        cell
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        cell
    </td>
    <td>
        cell
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then, I add borders between the columns with this css:

```
td:not(:last-child){
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
```

But then I get spaces on the border between each row D:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

How can I get rid of these spaces?

http://jsfiddle.net/Tgr48/

Comment: The images do not illustrate the issue; they look identical.

Comment: Oh, it seems that the issue is the small spacing between the borders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collapsing the table border will do that:

```
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
```